# Как подключиться к домашней группе через ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, сеть, администрирование

Имеется небольшая wi-fi сеть. На одном компьютере с windows 7 создана домашняя группа. Компьютер с ubuntu видит эту группу, но не может к ней подключиться, выходит ошибка: "Не удалось подключить местоположение, ошибка подключения к ресурсу Windows". До вопроса о паролей дело не доходит. В самбе workgroup прописал правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `smb.conf` изменить значение на ваше имя пользователя, не root (`guest account = %username%`). И перезагрузить командой: `sudo service samba restart` (если не поможет, то `sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart`). Если не поможет это решение, можно, пожалуйста, логи (`cat /var/log/samba/log.имяsmbклиента`).

Comment: В `smb.conf` строки `guest account` не нашел. Дописал сам. 
Команда `sudo service samba restart` выдала `samba: unrecognized service`.
Команда `samba: unrecognized service` - `samba: unrecognized service`.
Папка с логами пустая

Comment: @ИльданКиамов пробовали рестарт компьютера с ubuntu? Какой у вас smb клиент?